# Pivot table with registers duplicate in 2 row

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a question about how to summarize a list of data, I attached an image of how the data is presented.
The question is how to determine (summarize) the total of activities per unit considering that a person works in 2 units.
You could define that the person working in A / B does 50% of activities for each unit.
As the list of registers is very extensive the idea is to be able to automate, try with a PivotTable and did not give me result.
Any suggestions would be appreciated (xls, sql, etc).

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxTjP.png)

http://ge.tt/381feDj2 -> Excel fILE

Comment: You can use the `COUNTIFS` if you have defined variables. Example would be `=COUNTIFS(G4:G21,"A",I4:I21,"UNO",J4:J21,"CORRER")`

Comment: OK, but in the column unidad exist "A/B", These values ​​must be added to both A and B.

Comment: Add an asterix before and after the A: `"*A*"` . This was it looks for A anywhere in the Cell String.

Comment: Ok thank you that work but i need make that with pivot table because i dont know all values of column actividad. This column is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Am really not the best of people when it comes to Pivot Tables, but assuming i know what you are asking for.
1) Add one extra column (dummy) and just put 1 in it, this will be used to sum the number of events that the criteria occurs.
2) Select the whole table and then Insert=>Pivot Tables
3) Click Ok
4) Set Rows (fecha); Values (dummy); and the rest to Filters.

[image: PIVOT TABLE]

Then you can choose to filter your output the way you want. If you want A and A/B you can select multiple in the filter options.